# Nakajima reflection functors and the flavour/framing group action

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, geometric-representation-theory, quiver-varieties

Nakajima has constructed so-called *reflection functors* that are isomorphisms between different quiver varieties that have the same framing $\mathbf{w}:$ 
$$\Phi_{\sigma}:\mathfrak{M}_\zeta(Q,\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})\rightarrow \mathfrak{M}_{\sigma \cdot \zeta}(\sigma*_\mathbf{w} \mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}),$$
Here $\sigma\in W$ is an element of the Weyl group for Kac-Moody Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_Q.$
The question is: Is it known/written somewhere how do these maps combine with $\operatorname{GL}(\mathbf{w})$-actions on the both sides? E.g. is it equivariant with respect to them? Moreover, is it equivariant with respect to the $\mathbb{C}^*$-action that acts by weight $1$ on all edges of the quiver $Q$? I am interested in ADE types only, but I guess the answer does not depend on that.

Comment: Just to add now: There is a paper "Etingof conjecture for quantized quiver varieties" by Bezrukavnikov-Losev which deals with the related question. They claim rather a twisted-equivariant property of reflection functor, with respect to a subgroup of $GL(\mathbf{w})\times \mathbb{C}^*.$